# Автоматический перенос из Confluence в базу знаний Bitrix24

Tags: импорт, битрикс24, confluence

Всем здоровья!

Подскажите пожалуйста, какими методами можно автоматически и эффективно перенести все данные из Confluence в "Базу знаний" Bitrix24 без потери информации и структуры?

Может у кого есть опыт или полезная информация.

Comment: 1. Готового решения на Маркете нет. 2. Запросите миграцию у вендора (поддержка решения) - могут или перенести или подсказать. 3. Спросите на профильных форумах, на SO другого рода вопросы. 4. Когда дойдете до этого пункта - значит придется делать свой скрипт или переносить вручную.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://konstantinbulgakov.com/post/9558) написано как можно выгрузить данные в CVS/XML.

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо!